# Mysql select where id in multiple ids

Tags: mysql, sql

There was one problem and I can not find a solution.

I have table something like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `system_tests_run` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `questions_id` text NOT NULL,
  `run_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_to` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_from` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `class` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `minutes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;



INSERT INTO `system_tests_run` (`id`, `test_id`, `questions_id`, `run_id`, `created`, `date_to`, `date_from`, `class`, `minutes`) VALUES
(1, 1, '1', 1, '2014-03-02 16:59:07', '2014-03-02 17:05:00', '2014-03-02 16:58:00', '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', 15);
```

and i using this query for load data joined with table users,

```
SELECT r.date_from, 
       r.date_to, 
       r.id, 
       t.name, 
       t.subject, 
       u.meno, 
       u.priezvisko 
  FROM `system_tests_run` r 
       LEFT JOIN system_tests t 
                 ON t.id = r.test_id 
       LEFT JOIN system_users u 
                 ON u.id = r.run_id 
 WHERE r.class IN (1) 
       AND r.date_from <= NOW() 
       AND r.date_to >= NOW();
```

This table is for online exam testing, and in field class i store name of class for example (2) , my query working only for 1st class, if had for example in where clause **WHERE r.class IN (2)** so the command will not work

Query works fine if i use **WHERE r.class IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)**  but i need only one, Because the student has only one class and for the class may be directed test, not all
You can not think of any solution suitable for me? 
Thanks,.

Comment: It's unclear, what you asking

Comment: I need select row ONLY ONE VALUE FROM field class. for example 2, and its not working if field has stored data (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9) ... select * from system_tests_run WHERE class IN (2) .. for example query.

Comment: That looks like japanese to me

Comment: Don't understand either. Do you want to get only one result? Order by some parameter, and use `LIMIT 1` to retrieve only the first row. You can use `UNION` or maybe the `COALESCE` function to fill in in case of nonexistent data. Or maybe `GROUP`. Best of all would be to supply an example or, even better, a SQL Fiddle (sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Just a guess,add `GROUP BY t.name HAVING COUNT(r.class)=the number of elements in IN` in your case with IN(2) is 1 element

Comment: Sorry guys my english is very bad i know  but im trying to write it, ... i have a system, exam system for teaching students in school, teacher create test, now he need run test, they select classes from multiple selectbox ...and stored in the database(system_test_run classes) as 5,7,9. Everything is ok for students 5. class, if i logged with student 7.class,9.class , result is empty, but cannot be empty... i think i dont need any group and limits, main problem is in  WHERE r.class IN ().

Comment: Create a fiddle the sql language is universal and much more precise.http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: here is working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adc37/8 , here is not working query  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adc37/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REGEXP`,but you should really learn about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adc37/21)

Comment: Thanks you, i read it, im not very good in sql/database, but im learning

Comment: @user2982550 Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574